# Tomcat environment variable wrong value

Tags: windows, tomcat, environment-variables

I am facing this problem :

the CATLALINA_HOME environment variable contains this value:
"**?C:\Tomcat**" instead of "**C:\Tomcat**".
I don't know where this "?" comes from.
I am working on Windows.
thanks

Comment: The correct name of the variable should be CATALINA_HOME and not CATLALINA_HOME

Answer (score 1):

Usually that variable comes from catalina.sh or catalina.bat look for this files in your Tomcat/bibn folder.

If you're working on Windows just open the file .bat: catalina.bat